# How to Store a table records count into global variable vba msaccess

Tags: vba

i declare a public var as integer to store the record's count of a table with vba code.

using this code

```
public @VarName as integer
@VarName = Dcount("*","TBL_Name")
```

and seems the dcount not working in public mode.

how can i create such code?

Comment: Hoover your mouse on the tags you want to use to see their description and use the proper ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function TotalCount() As Long
    TotalCount = DCount("*", "TBL_Name")
End Function
```

You can then call it:

```
ModuleName.TotalCount
```